# Can we add path of other fixture files in a fixture.json in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

the idea is that I want to use operations and each operation have a name and a fixture file  ,
each path have a file that contains data.
and I have a command that get me the fixture file just by calling the operation name, the main question here is if this code is correct in json file for fixture :

```
{
    "stremeadConfig": "./alerts-escalation-param.stremead.json",
    "screenIds": [],
    "institutionInputId": "bank_code",
    "screenLabels": {
      "searchLabels": "./alerts-escalation-param.search-labels.json",
      "detailsLabels": "./alerts-escalation-param.details-labels.json"
    },
    "search":  "./alerts-escalation-param.select.json",
    "searchCriteriaFields": [],
    "requiredFieldsOnSearchScreen": [],
    "requiredFieldsOnDetailsScreen": [],
    "operationsDefaultExpectedValues": {
      "numberOfColumnsOnEmptyRow": 1,
      "numberOfRecordsAfterDelete": 0
    },
    "existingDataToDelete": "./alerts-escalation-param.existing.json",
    "operations": [
      "./alerts-escalation-param.select.json",
      "./alerts-escalation-param.create.json",
      ".alerts-escalation-param.update.json",
      "./alerts-escalation-param.duplicate.json",
      "./alerts-escalation-param.delete.json"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a custom command that can load a fixture based on the specified operation.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('fixtureForOperation', (operation) => {
  return cy.fixture('my-fixtures.json').then(fixtureMain => {

    const fixturePath = fixtureMain.operations.find(path => {
      return path.contains(operation)
    })

    if (!fixturePath) {
      throw new Error('Operation not found in fixtures')
    })

    return cy.fixture(fixturePath)
  })
})
```

**test**

```js
cy.fixtureForOperation('duplicate').then(data => {
```

Answer (score 4):

The paths are just strings, so they can be stored in a JSON file.

For convenience, you want to remove `./` in front of fixture names. Import the lookup file at the top of the test.

```js
const fixtures = require('my-fixtures.json')

it('testing existingDataToDelete', () => {
  cy.fixture(fixtures.existingDataToDelete).then(data => {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this corrected json file

```
{
  "stremeadConfig": "./alerts-escalation-param.stremead.json",
  "screenIds": [],
  "institutionInputId": "bank_code",
  "screenLabels": {
  "searchLabels": "./alerts-escalation-param.search-labels.json",
  "detailsLabels": "./alerts-escalation-param.details-labels.json"
  },
  "search": "./alerts-escalation-param.select.json",
  "searchCriteriaFields": [],
  "requiredFieldsOnSearchScreen": [],
  "requiredFieldsOnDetailsScreen": [],
  "operationsDefaultExpectedValues": {
  "numberOfColumnsOnEmptyRow": 1,
  "numberOfRecordsAfterDelete": 0
 },
 "existingDataToDelete": "./alerts-escalation-param.existing.json",
 "operations": [
  {
   "name": "select",
   "fixture": "./alerts-escalation-param.select.json"
 },
 {
  "name": "create",
  "fixture": "./alerts-escalation-param.create.json"
 },
{
  "name": "update",
  "fixture": "./alerts-escalation-param.update.json"
},
{
  "name": "duplicate",
  "fixture": "./alerts-escalation-param.duplicate.json"
},
{
  "name": "delete",
  "fixture": "./alerts-escalation-param.delete.json"
}
 ]
}
```